# Encryption using Ant algorithms

Tags: optimization, encryption, cryptography, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I have seen research papers about using genetic algorithms and neural networks(neurocrypto) for encryption purposes. Can't we use ant colony optimization algorithms for encryption? Is there any recent attempts?

Comment: So, do you have some new information about using ant colony optimization algorithms for encryption?

Answer (score 2):

I can't really think of a way to use Ant colony optimization algorithms for encryption, but I know of attempts to use them for Cryptanalysis and decryption.

[This](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5480260) paper is an attempt to use Ant Colony Optimization to do a cryptanalysis of four-rounded DES, they use the swarm to look for the secret key on a directed graph they constructed.

Hope that helps.